# How to have many consumer threads using BlockingCollection

Tags: c#-4.0, producer-consumer

I am using a producer / consumer pattern backed with a BlockingCollection to read data off a file, parse/convert and then insert into a database. The code I have is very similar to what can be found here: http://dhruba.name/2012/10/09/concurrent-producer-consumer-pattern-using-csharp-4-0-blockingcollection-tasks/

However, the main difference is that my consumer threads not only parse the data but also insert into a database. This bit is slow, and I think is causing the threads to block.

In the example, there are two consumer threads. I am wondering if there is a way to have the number of threads increase in a somewhat intelligent way? I had thought a threadpool would do this, but can't seem to grasp how that would be done.

Alternatively, how would you go about choosing the number of consumer threads? 2 does not seem correct for me, but I'm not sure what the best # would be. Thoughts on the best way to choose # of consumer threads?

Comment: Threads are not a magic solution to every perf problem.  Adding more tends to either create just more waiting threads or a pissed-off dbase admin that doesn't like your app to completely hog the server.

Comment: This app would run during a scheduled downtime so the DB hit is acceptable. I just want to minimize the time it's down.

Comment: Does this have something to do with that downtime being at midnight and you just don't want stick around that long to try it?

Comment: Well I will NOT be the guy sticking around until midnight, but I'd like to make their lives easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to choose the number of consumer threads is math: figure out how many packets per minute are coming in from the producers, divide that by how many packets per minute a single consumer can handle, and you have a pretty good idea of how many consumers you need.

I solved the blocking output problem (consumers blocking when trying to update the database) by adding another `BlockingCollection` that the consumers put their completed packets in. A separate thread reads that queue and updates the database. So it looks something like:

```
input thread(s) => input queue => consumer(s) => output queue => output thread
```

This has the added benefit of divorcing the consumers from the output, meaning that you can optimize the output or completely change the output method without affecting the consumer. That might allow you, for example, to batch the database updates so that rather than making one database call per record, you could update a dozen or a hundred (or more) records with a single call.

I show a very simple example of this (using a single consumer) in my article [Simple Multithreading, Part 2](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/07/18/simple-multithreading-part-2/). That works with a text file filter, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: This is awesome! batching the DB updates sounds like exactly what I need.